# Kernel patch for xenomai

Tags: pi-3b+, raspberry-pi-os, freertos, xenomai

I want to have xenomai RTOS on my raspberry pi 3B
The xenomai ipipe-arm patch with rpi-linux as I see the linux version is 6.1.y and ipipe-arm patch does not have latest patch.
I'm trying to patch the same version 4.19 with 4.19 then too its getting unable to patch the kernel
Do you have idea about?